# PHP/MYSQL - Error Array ( ) string(47) "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (!$errors) {
$salt = time();
$pwd = sha1($password . $salt); 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit(); 
}
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$username,$pwd,$lastloggedin,$role,$paswordchangedate,$salt);
```

This is my code snippet, I have counted, countless times (on my fingers too..)- connection works, did a var_dump($mysqli->error) to get the error. When logging into Mysql and describing the table I get 7 rows

```
Field             Type         Null  Key  Default  Extra
id                 int(11)     No    Pri  Null     auto_increment
username           varchar(50) Yes   Uni  Null   
password           varchar(50) Yes        Null
lastloggedin       datetime    Yes        Null
role               varchar(20) Yes        Null
paswwordchangedate datetime    Yes        Null
salt               int(11)     Yes        Null
```

Comment: You're inserting 6 values to a 7-value row. (id, username, password, lastloggedin, role, paswwordchangedate, salt). Use NULL for the id.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (null,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$username,$pwd,$lastloggedin,$role,$paswordchangedate,$salt);
```

Note I added the first value to be `Null` to autoincrement, you were missing the id field.

Remember that when you don't specify the field name you have to make sure every field is included.

This should work too:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,lastloggedin,role,paswwordchangedate,salt)
          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ;";
```

Comment: Better solution is to name all fields. If he will add new field in that db table, he will again have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use the `INSERT ... SET ...` format like this:

```
$query = "
            INSERT INTO users
            SET
                username = ?,
                password = ?,
                lastloggedin = ?,
                role = ?,
                paswwordchangedate = ?,
                salt = ?
";
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$username,$pwd,$lastloggedin,$role,$paswordchangedate,$salt);
```

That way, according to the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html), values not listed in the `SET` clause will be assigned to their default values (`null` in the case of your `id` field, which will be translated to an integer, due to your `auto_increment` property for that column).

Note that this particular syntax will allow you to add multiple columns in the case you need them, only specifying what your really need in the `INSERT` statement and letting other columns with their default value automatically.